# Bash in ConEmu on windows is too slow

Tags: command-prompt, conemu

Have you faced issue while using bash in ConEmu on Windows? It is generally slower than CMD(in ConEmu) and if I SSH through bash it gets painfully slow. Anything you can suggest to improve the performance?

Or any other tool like ConEmu that you you prefer?

Comment: "Slow" does not describe anything.

Comment: Untag this from bash … this actually isn't a bash question per se.

Comment: @MikeQ untagged

Comment: @Maximus Typing in cmd in ConEmu seems natural, in bash it occasionally feels slow and sluggish. If I use SSH then typing becomes super slow, I can understand that executing commands is going to be slower but slow typing is really odd. I hope you can suggest a solution as I enjoy using it and wouldn't want to replace it. Thanks.

Comment: @Maximus Alright, it is not ConEmu issue, just how SSH works. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add a data point, I absolutely see high latencies with conemu+wslbridge.  Running the default wsl.exe prompt, things are very responsive.  conemu, OTOH, I see delays of 0.5-1s between something like 'ls' and any output.

Answer (score 1):

I installed conEMU ver 180626 "preview" 64bit connected with cmd no issues. Then I installed cmder and started a bash session and noticed that shell was a little slow locally but connected over ssh (AWS EC2 over 2G WiFi) and it performed well there.

Maybe install cmder if you haven't already, I think you probably have, I chose to run {bash::bash as admin}

Also I recommend to test with :
FileZilla for SFTP file transfers .
PuTTY for SSH terminals.

Comment: Thanks, I will try cmder. I tried SSH but couldn't connect to gitlab so gave up on that. But I am comfortable using bash except for the slow input.

Comment: I downloaded an EXE, no need for git

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to say I tried Putty but couldn't get it to connect to gitlab.

Comment: Just a note: cmder can't be faster than ConEmu, because it is ConEmu + tools.

Comment: Ya I looked it up, I am sticking with ConEmu.

Comment: @Maximus , In my case, things are opposite. Conemu is slow in WSL (win 10 1809), when i open or save a file with nano, it usually took me ~3-4s while Cmder "mini" or Hyper took constant time to open/save using nano.